# IoT Edge proxy configuration

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

We are trying to make IoT edge work with specific proxy configuration works over communication having speed of 800kb/s

Our proxy configuration only allows HTTP communication only for whitelisted URL or by specific Proxy configuration URL.

We have added proxy configuration URL in IoTedge.service, Docker.service HTTP confidence and IoTedge.service HTTP conf but didn't got any success

Did anyone has experienced this issue. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, currently IoT edge does not support proxy.With out http proxy support in azure-iot-sdk-csharp device sdk, Azure/iot-edge cannot communicate using AMQP_WS over HTTP proxies. 
Please refer to Github issue at [issue#5](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/5) and [issue#465](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/465).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and mentioning issue#5. Would it be possible to know any release calendar of IoTedge to know when proxy support will be provided

Comment: Sorry, I could not get the calendar.